# XAML MediaElement Play() method not working in code

Tags: windows-phone, mediaelement

Hi I have a Windows Phone app with a MediaElement window defined in XAML to play a video file:

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="mediaWindow" MediaEnded="mediaWindow_MediaEnded" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="225" Margin="15,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

When I call this in C# code it play fine:?

```
 mediaWindow.Source = new Uri(loc, UriKind.Relative);
```

But something strange is happening eg when the user navigates to a new page a MediaElement on that page should kickin and play an audio file but I doesn't. If I comment out the code above which play the video then the audio file on the navigated to page works OK.

I've tried using in XAML:?

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="mediaWindow" MediaEnded="mediaWindow_MediaEnded" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="225" Margin="15,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

and in C#:

```
 mediaWindow.Source = new Uri(loc, UriKind.Relative);
 mediaWindow.Play();
```

But this just shows a black screen!?

These is another MediaElement defined in XAML on the original page which I use to play an audio file, could this be the problem? If so what can I do to play the audio file and a video file on the same page? I've read I could use MediaPlayer for the audio file but I tried defining that in c# code but it does not exixt in namespace even though I have included:

```
 using System.Windows.Media;
```

This is driving me crazy, new to C#, help appreciated here.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving the source of the video within the `XAML`? and make the `AutoPlay` to false.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaSimple" 
          Source="Videos/video1.mp4" 
          Stretch="UniformToFill" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

and give the `mediaSimple.Play()` within a button click event handler.

Comment: I had one of the MediaElement sources defined within XAML and the other one defined in c# at runtime. I think I solved it using 1 MediaElement and setting their source at runtime 1 for the audio and the other for video when needed. I am now able to use the same MediaElement for both...not sure if this option is a good idea ATM but it seems to work for now!?